# boundingRectWithSize crash with emoji

Tags: ios, crash, emoji

when I use boundingRectWithSize to calculate the height of the text，it crash.I find it maybe because the text have some emoji.
Somebody can tell me how to solve this.

```
    CGFloat kScreenMargin = 15.;
    CGFloat kScreenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

    self.content = @"Eefggg‍‍";

    CGFloat contentH = [self.content boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(kScreenWidth - 2 * kScreenMargin, MAXFLOAT)
                                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]} context:nil].size.height;
```

[Here is the crash screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czWts.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You first convert into Encoding string and then get height:

```
CGFloat kScreenMargin = 15.;
    CGFloat kScreenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
NSString *strEmo = @"Eefggg‍‍"
NSData *data = [strEmo dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.content = goodValue;
CGFloat contentH = [self.content boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(kScreenWidth - 2 * kScreenMargin, MAXFLOAT)
                                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]} context:nil].size.height;
```

Comment: How to do Chinese？

Comment: @iCloudy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619316/chiness-charecter-encoding-issue-iphone